# how to display the currency symbol?

Tags: magento, symbols

I used the following code for to display the currency symbol

```
    <?php $_coreHelper = $this->helper('core')?>
     <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency('5'); ?>
```

it displayed like Rs253

I want to display as Rs5

I dont know how to fix it.If anybody know, please help me guys, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe $this does not have access to `helper()`

Try

`<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency(5); ?>`

Comment: Thank you for your response.Now also it displays Rs253

Comment: @DRAJI Sorry I didn't really read your question well enough, it is very strange, is Rs your default currency? Maybe you need to define the specify currency.